# Simulink scope limit

Tags: simulink

I am running a simulink model in external simulation mode and am having the following problem: When I stop the simulation and get the data from the scope, it never saves more than the last 5,000 data points. I have tried unchecking "Limit data points to last:" checkbox, but that doesn't help. I also tried increasing that number to 10,000 but there was no difference in the number of points I was able to save.

I found that if I create a new model and set it to normal simulation mode, then I can save as many data points as I want. Can anyone explain why I might have this issue in external simulation but not normal simulation?

Comment: In external mode, data logging is effected by the Duration setting on the External Signal and Triggering panel of the External Mode Control Panel.  Go to that panel and press the Help button for a description of Duration and how to change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can now set duration to whatever I want. I would accept your answer, but it is currently just a comment...

Comment: I've made it an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In external mode, data logging is effected by the Duration setting on the External Signal and Triggering panel of the External Mode Control Panel. Go to that panel and press the Help button for a description of Duration and how to change it